# FK (mysql-db) using Sequalize.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

When I pass data through Sequalize.js to my db, everything is stored correctly besides the FK "shops_ID" in the food table which is still null.

I've read other similar topics but none have helped.

I would appreciate any help/guidance.

I'm using mysql with following db-setup

```
Shops (mysql-table)
- id (pk)
- shopName

Food (mysql-table)
- id (pk)
- foodName
- shops_ID (fk connected to "id" in shops table)
```

shops.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../database/db_shops.js"); //DB connection

const shops = db.sequelize.define(
  "shops",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    shopName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
);
module.exports = shops;
```

food.js

```
"use strict";
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../database/db_shops.js"); //DB connection
var shops = require("../models/shops");

const food = db.sequelize.define(
  "food",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    foodName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    shops_ID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: "shops",
        key: "id"
      }
    }
  }
);
module.exports = food;
```

association.js

```
const food = require("./food");
const shops = require("./shops");
food.belongsTo(shops, { foreignKey: "shops_ID" });
module.exports = { food: food, shops: shops };
```

(EDIT)
and this is how I post my data to mysql-db:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("../models/association.js");
const Shops = db.shops;
const Foods = db.food;

router.use(cors());

router.post("/sell", (req, res, next) => {
  var data = req.body.foodDefined;
  var food = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    food.push({
      foodName: data[i].foodName,
    });
  }
  const shops = {
    shopsName: req.body.shopsName,
  };
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.send(errors);
  } else {
    Shops.create(shops) 
      .then(Shops => {
        Foods.bulkCreate(food);
        res.json({ status: Shops.shopsName + " Registered!" });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.send("error: " + err);
      });
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Show us how you store data

Comment: @rkm I've added the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shops_ID` is not stored, because you don't set it. `food` object only has single property `foodName`. You should add shop ID to each food:

```
...
const preparedFood = food.map(item => {
  item.shops_ID = Shops.id;
  return item;
});
Food.bulkCreate(preparedFood);
```

It's worth noting that `Foods.bulkCreate` is async method which means that when you are sending response `food` is not stored yet and if it fails you will get error since you cannot send two responses. To solve it you can either use `await` or send a response in another `.then` block.